# how to use post method to create api in laravel

Tags: laravel, rest, api, http-post, postman

I am beginner to Laravel and Rest API creation. I am trying to create api to search trader is exist or not depending on contact number using post method.

My `api.php` page has

`Route::post('/traders/searchTrader/', 'API\TradersController@searchTrader');`

my `TraderController` has

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\API\BaseController as BaseController;
use App\Trader;
use Validator;



 class TradersController extends BaseController
    {
     public function searchTrader(Request $request)
        {

    if (Trader::where('traders_contact_number', $request)->exists()) {
        //traders_contact_number exists in Trader table
        return $this->sendResponse($trader->toArray(), 'Trader is Exist.');
     }
     return $this->sendError('Trader not exist.');

        }
    }
```

My url in postman is like `http://cms.test:8082/api/traders/searchTrader` with post method selected. And in body tab I am giving inputs like  traders_contact_number as key and some value which exists in table and not exists in table traders.

Now I an getting  `Trader not exist.` output everytime. I am not getting how to debug this in postman or on browser to check the query or request getting number and that is checking in my table.

I tried by changing `if` structure like follows

```
 public function searchTrader(Request $request)
    {
 $trader = Trader::where('traders_contact_number', $request->traders_contact_number)->first();
// dd($trader);die();
        if (is_null($trader)) {
            return $this->sendError('Trader not exist.');
        }
 return $this->sendResponse($trader->toArray(), 'Trader is Exist.');

}
```

But this also giving me `Trader not exist` output. What going wrong here? How do I check query getting correct value or how to debug this? How to use post method to create API?

Please guide.

Comment: put `return $trader;` after `$trader = Trader::where('traders_contact_number', $request->traders_contact_number)->first();` in the second function

Comment: @Zain Farooq is it  `return $trader;` to debug ? I tried that. it showing blank on postman.  I have set the headers (accept, content-type to application-json) on postman.

Comment: Ok. put `return $request->traders_contact_number;` after `public function searchTrader(Request $request)`

Comment: @Zain Farooq return should be inside the function. after `public function searchTrader(Request $request)` giving me syntax error.

Comment: Yes. should be inside the function `public function searchTrader(Request $request)
    {`

Comment: @Zain Farooq the problem was with the headers Content-type: application/json . I removed that and now its working. But Thanks for giving hint to debug.